# Servico nao sobe

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

Tenho um servico [arquivo.svc.cs] mas ele nao sobe, tento acessar ele com ajax e da not found.
Alguem sabe como resolvo isso, o que pode estar errado.?

```
namespace Bob.Servico
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Usuario" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Usuario.svc or Usuario.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Usuario : IUsuario
    {
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public GetUsuarioDAO GetUsuario(GetUsuarioRequestDAO usuario)
        {
            log.Info("Iniciando GetUsuario");
            var retorno = new GetUsuarioDAO();

            using (var db = new BobDataContext())
            {

                var result = db.sp_usuario_select(null, usuario.email, usuario.cpf, usuario.senha).Select(r => new GetUsuarioDAO()
                {
                    email = r.email,
                    cpf = r.cpf,
                    nome = r.nome,
                    nome_usuario = r.nome_usuario,
                    sexo = r.sexo,
                    data_nascimento = Convert.ToString(r.data_nascimento),
                    id = r.id,
                    celular = r.celular,
                }).FirstOrDefault();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    retorno = result;
                    log.Info("GetUsuario - OK");
                    retorno.mensagens.Add(new MensagemDAO() { Mensagem = "OK", Tipo = Models.Enum.TipoMensagemEnum.Sucesso });
                }
                else
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (usuario.facebook_id) ){
                        log.Info("GetUsuario - nOK - Usuário ou senha inválidos.");
                        retorno.mensagens.Add(new MensagemDAO() { Mensagem = "Usuário ou senha inválidos!.", Tipo = Models.Enum.TipoMensagemEnum.Erro});

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        log.Info("GetUsuario - OK - Não encontrou nenhum usuário.");
                        retorno.mensagens.Add(new MensagemDAO() { Mensagem = "0", Tipo = Models.Enum.TipoMensagemEnum.Aviso });

                    }

                }
            }

            return retorno;
        }

    }
}
```

```js
function inicio() {
  $("span.help-block").hide();
  alert("2");
  $(document).on("click", "#btn_esqueci_senha", function() {
    window.location = "esqueci-senha.html";
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#btn_validar", function() {

    $("#aviso").hide();
    $("#aviso").find("p").html("");

    if (validar()) {
      alert("3");
      var email = null;
      var cpf = null;

      if ($("[name=email]").val() == "" || $("[name=email]").length == 0) {
        cpf = $("[name=cpf]").val();
      } else {
        email = $("[name=email]").val();
      }

      var usuario = {
        email: email,
        cpf: cpf,
        senha: $("#txt_senha").val()
      };

      //var usuario = getFormData($("#usuario"));
      alert(email);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../sistema/Bob.Servico/Usuario.svc.cs/GetUsuario",
        cache: false,
        //crossdomain:true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(usuario),
        success: function(data) {

          alert("teste zombie 4 :( ");

          console.log(data);
          if (data.GetUsuarioResult.mensagens[0].Mensagem == "0") {
            window.location = "dados-complementares.html";
          } else if (data.GetUsuarioResult.mensagens[0].Mensagem == "OK") {

            window.localStorage.setItem("usuario", JSON.stringify(data.GetUsuarioResult));
            window.location = "home.html";
          } else {
            alert(data.GetUsuarioResult.mensagens[0].Mensagem);
          }
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert(error)
        }

      });

    }
  });


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <title>site</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/custom.css">

  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
</head>

<body onload="onDeviceReady()">

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="wrapper">

      <!-- Main Header -->
      <header class="main-header">

        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="home.html" class="logo">
          <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
          <span class="logo-mini"></span>
          <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
          <span class="logo-lg"></span>
        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar -->

      </header>

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="div-beta"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-8 text-center painel" id="conteudo">
              <h1 class="painel-content">
                LOGIN
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row dnone" id="aviso">
              <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4>
                  <i class="icon fa fa-warning"></i> Aviso!
                </h4>
                <p></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
      <!-- Control Sidebar -->
      <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
      <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
                immediately after the control sidebar -->
    </div>


    <div class="login-box">
      <div class="login-logo">
        <a href="/">
          <p>
            <img src="images/logo.jpeg" width="140" height="100" />
        </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.login-logo -->
      <div class="login-box-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Iniciar sessão</p>

        <form role="form" name="dados" id="usuario" onsubmit="return false">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="txt_email_cpf">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            <span class="help-block help-block-email_cpf">Este campo é obrigatório!</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="txt_senha">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
            <span class="help-block help-block-esqueci-senha">Este campo é obrigatório!</span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              <div class="checkbox icheck">
                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="lembrarme"> Lembrar me
                                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-8 form-group">
              <button type="submit" id="btn_validar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Logar</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-8 form-group">
              <button type="button" id="btn_esqueci_senha" class="btn bg-purple marginbtn-esqueci-senha">Esqueci a senha</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-8 form-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-cadastro">CADASTRO

                            </button>

            </div>

            <!-- /.col -->
          </div>
        </form>
        <!--
                <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
                    <p>- OR -</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in using
                    Facebook</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Sign in using
                    Google+</a>
                </div>
                <!- - /.social-auth-links -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.login-box-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-box -->



    <!-- Main Footer -->

    <footer class="main-footer">
      <!-- To the right -->
      <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
        <a href="https://www.site.com.br" target="_blank"><img src="img/logo-min.jpg" height="30"></a>
      </div>
      <!-- Default to the left -->
      <span>Copyright &copy; 2018 <b> site</b>.</span> Todos os direitos reservados.
    </footer>


  <!--</div>-->
  <!-- /.container -->
  <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
  <script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <script src="plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>


  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
        increaseArea: '20%' // optional
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Se você expor o seu código e  mostrar como está fazendo a publicação e como está acessando via javascript... a gente vai saber como resolver.

Comment: Cara, você tá fazendo uma bagunça aqui... recomendo você remover essa pergunta e fazer uma nova de forma mais organizada. Dê uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: tem limite de caracteres pra responder muito ruim isso, por isso coloquei nova resposta.

Comment: Vc tem a opção de editar a pergunta, sem precisar postar novas respostas @hyperpixel

Comment: tudo bem, qual forma correta, quero resolver a app!!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro ponto, você está chamando a url errado no seu `ajax`, não existe o `.cs` depois do `.svc`

```
url: "../sistema/Bob.Servico/Usuario.svc/GetUsuario",
```

Você precisa apontar para um endpoint válido, pelo endereço que você atribuiu à `url`, me dá a impressão de que está tentando acessar um endereço além da raiz do seu site, em outra estrutura, e como se fosse um recurso estático.

O seu web service precisa ser disponibilizado em um host como uma aplicação, se não for no mesmo ambiente do seu site. Se o serviço está hospedado em um outro site, você precisa apontar com o caminho completo para ele:

```
url: "http://endereco_do_ws/Usuario.svc/GetUsuario",
```

Ainda assim, por se tratar de uma chamada ajax, você ainda precisa fazer as configurações para a habilitar a requisição `CORS` para não ter problema com `cross-dmain`.

Comment: esta local, localhost na pasta um nivel acima da www

/sistema  
/www

Comment: Certo e ao acessar o Usuario.svc pelo browser, o que aparece? e qual endereço você usa para isso?

Comment: Nao entendi muito bem, relativo a isso? omiti [comentei] fica dando monte de erro no console do crome :    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">